# How to igonre parameter with "send method"

Tags: ruby

```
def some_operation ids, action, params
  ids.each do |_id|
    groups.find(_id).send(action, params)
  end
end
some_operation('reserve',:queue=>self})
some_operation('unreserve')
```

this doesn't work for `unreserve`, because `unreserve` doesn't have parameters and I should not change the method reserve. Any good idea how I should change the method `some_operation` so it can ignore parameter for `unreserve`????

Comment: `groups` is an unspecified method with no arguments? `}` in `:queue=>self}` is misplaced.

Comment: groups is another model. `groups.find(_id)` this is used to find an instance of group model

Comment: If this is a Rails question you need a Rails tag.

Comment: @caryswoveland it is a ruby question. And I found solution. I can do `def some_operation ids, action, *params` and `groups.find(_id).send(action, *params)` to solve this issue.

Comment: I believe "model" is a Rails concept (but I don't know Rails). Ruby does not have models. `groups` can only be a method or a local variable. If it were the latter an exception would have been raised because it has not been previously defined within the method. As no answers have been posted, if you no longer need one you should delete the question.